# How can I put a link in a comment?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

How can I put a link in a comment using Markdown?

Comment: Dupe of the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757

Comment: I always just cut-and-paste the link in.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the little question mark above the top-right of the text box, it explains how to use Markdown in text boxes, including links, italics, bold, code blocks, and more. Here is the page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: That's for the main text for a question or answer - not for comments per se.

Comment: just a test http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50548/189547