# How to link posts

Tags: support, linked-questions

I posted a question on Stack Overflow which is a follow on from a question I posted a few days earlier. Is there anyway for me to link that previous post to my current post, or do only moderators have that ability?

Comment: Just post a link to it and it will appear automagically under the "linked" questions to the right.

Comment: I meant the little links that appear to the right of the page (above the Related list of links)

Comment: Apologies, but another question - I can link to my previous page by linking like you said, but how do I get it to appear to the right of the page in a "Linked" section (above the "Related" section)?

Comment: [example link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50545). Note that this question will now appear in the "Linked" section on the right side.

Comment: @Kevin: Got it - it just took a minute for the link to appear at the side.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help!